# How to get incoming InputStream, in controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I need to get an incoming input stream for an uploaded file from the front-side in an ASP.NET controller and then forward it elsewhere, can anyone tell me how to access it? I saw some comments that say that I can get the way below but I get a compile error if I do that:

```
var requestStream=HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're in a controller, then `this.Request.InputStream` should have what you need.

Comment: But the strean will only be accessible when the request completes, not good for large files, is there a way to process the stream while it's being received?

Answer (score 1):

if the use uploaded a file you can added a `HttpPostedFileBase` to the action to access the file.

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    using(var stream = file.InputStream)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks useful, but I get a null pointer when I try it, how do I know what the variable name is supposed to be?

Comment: it's the name of the input on the form. make sure the form include the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`